# How to deal when testing with eth brownie for a sender with not enough balance

Tags: brownie

I'm trying in my tests to simulate a situation where a sender calls a payable method of a contract but does not have enough balance.
A sample code would be:

```
with brownie.reverts():
   contract.buy({'from': accounts[0], 'value': 100000000000000000000000000})
```

Instead of the test continuing I get a ValueError:

`E ValueError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 100000000000000000000000000 and the sender's account only has: 100000000000000000000`

How do I catch such errors with brownie?

Answer (score 0):

You try to send more eth than is on account balance. If you use use `ganache-cli` the initial balance of each account is `100 eth`. You can create account of bigger balance by collecting all eth into single account, as follow:

Create following `brownie-config.yaml`:

```yaml
networks:
  default: development
  development:
    cmd_settings:
      accounts: 50
```

where you can change `50` to your desired number. Then create `script.py` file in `scripts/` directory with following code:

```py
from brownie import accounts, Wei

def main():
    print('initial number of accounts ', len(accounts))
    balance = accounts[0].balance()
    print('initial balance of account_0 in Eth ', Wei(balance).to('ether'))

    # transfer all eth into account_0
    for i in range(1, len(accounts)):
        amount = accounts[i].balance()
        accounts[i].transfer(accounts[0], amount)

    balance = accounts[0].balance()
    print('final balance of account_0 in Eth ', Wei(balance).to('ether'))
```

Run:

```sh
brownie run scripts/script.py
```

to check final balance of `accounts[0]` EOA

**Warning**: It loops over all accounts and make transfer for each of them, so for big `accounts` number script can run really slow